# How to create custom predicate for criteria jpa2 (hibernate)?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa-2.0, hibernate-criteria, jpa-2.1

I'm trying migrate to JPA2 Criteria API (Hibernate as JPA provider) from the old one. I have a problem with custom criteria for PostgreSQL JSONB type. In the previous Criteria implementation it can be done by creating SQLCriterion where I can operate directly on native SQL. In the JPA2 implementation I cannot find similar solution so I have decided to extend AbstractSimplePredicate.

Here simple version:

```
   class JsonEqual<Y> extends AbstractSimplePredicate {

    private static final String JSON_NESTED_FIELD_EXTRACTOR = "->>";
    private static final String JSON_EQUAL_OPERATOR = "=";
    private final Expression<?> field;
    private final Expression<?> value;
    private final Path<Y> path;

    public JsonEqual(CriteriaBuilderImpl cb, Path<Y> path, Expression<?> field, Expression<?> value) {
        super(cb);
        this.path = path;
        this.field = field;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerParameters(ParameterRegistry registry) {
        Helper.possibleParameter(path, registry);
        Helper.possibleParameter(field, registry);
        Helper.possibleParameter(value, registry);
    }

    @Override
    public String render(boolean isNegated, RenderingContext renderingContext) {
        return ((Renderable) path).render(renderingContext)
                        + JSON_NESTED_FIELD_EXTRACTOR
                        + ((Renderable) field).render(renderingContext)
                        + JSON_EQUAL_OPERATOR
                        + ((Renderable) value).render(renderingContext);
    }
}
```

Problem occurs when jpa2 criteria is compiled to HQL. Query part rendered by predicate is incorrect format ('->>' operator is not recognized).

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: > near line 1, column 515 [select new com.hibernate.VenueEntity(generatedAlias0.id) from com.hibernate.VenueEntity as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias0.metadata->>:param3=:param4 ) order by generatedAlias0.created asc]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:291) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:186) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:553) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:3324) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl$1.buildCompiledQuery(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:3617) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:203) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
```

Is there any possibility to implement custom Predicate for JPA2 in this situation?

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this question as well. But just in case you're a pinch and didn't think of this.... I have worked around similar issues by just creating a custom postgresql function as a wrapper around some of pg's proprietary operators. Then can access it as a function from JPA criteria queries.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I heard about this workaround but I want implement something more elegant. If I won't find better solution here then I'll use function wrapper.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. It was just in case you needed it working asap.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried to do such thing with JSONB, but I did with arrays and the `&&` operator.
So, I think, the following solution will address your case:

1. Create and register custom Postgres dialect which extends the standard one.
2. In dialect - `registerFunction("json_extract", 
       new SQLFunctionTemplate(HibernateTypeWhichYouNeed.INSTANCE, "(?1 ->> ?2)"));`
3. In client code - 
   `cb.equal(
   cb.function("json_extract", JavaClassWhichYouNeed.class, expr1, expr2),
   expr3);`